# How can I match everything with a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match("/^[MYEXPRESSION]+$/i", $anything)
```

What can I set `MYEXPRESSSION` to such that the above line always returns true?  Nothing outside the `MYEXPRESSION` character class can be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^[_]?|\]+$/i", $anything)
```

So `EXPRESSION = '_]?|\'`, you can replace the `_` portion with anything really...

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't seem possible

```
preg_match("/^[.]+$/i", $anything)
```

would need at least one character to match. Changing MYEXPRESSION otherwise like to `.]*[.` won't help as long as the + sign is there there needs to be at least one character to match.

Comment: Same as for KilZone's answer: The `.` is a literal dot in between `[]`'s, not a wildcard for anything. It would require a literal `.` to be present.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The `+` quantifier requires at least one character so it won’t be able to match the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You've a `+` qualifier so that means at least one or more. In other words, it can never be set to not match anything *always*.

However, you can set `MYEXPRESSSION` to `^\r\n` so that it'll match *anything* but a *newline*.